# jQuery refreshing data in a html table

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery script that populates a table. How can I make the table update without appending the refresh from the MySql database. One the table is populated I want some form of refresh just to update the table content and not append to it. Any help with this would be great.

```
function refreshDataLiveRequests() {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'check_current_requests2.php',
data: $('#departcount').serialize(),
dataType: "json", //to parse string into JSON object,
success: function (data) {
if (data) {
  var len = data.length;
  var txt = "";
  if (len > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    if (data[i].Department && data[i].DepartCount) {

    txt += "<tr><td>" + data[i].Department + "</td><td>" + data[i].DepartCount + " </td></tr>";
    }
  }
  if (txt != "") {
    $("#table").append(txt);
  }
  }
}
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
}
});
return false;

}
setTimeout(refreshDataLiveRequests, 4000);
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to refresh it you're gonna have to append it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, I think you can give a id to the specific `<tr>` and change the innerHtml with the ajax call's response or you can have a id to the `<tbody>` and change the whole content of table with ajax call's response.